# How to integrate postfix and mimedefang

Tags: postfix

How do I use MIMEDefang with Postfix to filter email? I don't want to write an SMTPD handler and all the info I can find about MIMEDefang relates to how to use it with Sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either build or install `mimedefang` (I used yum as this was done on a CentOS 6.4 system). This will install sendmail also but don't be alarmed - it's a requirement for the software. If you are building note that you will need this dependency.

To write a milter using this process you need to search for and modify the file called `mimedefang-filter`. There are numerous samples available and depending on whether or not you did a self build or used an RPM there might be one or more available on your system. Put this file in **/etc/mail** and make sure it's executable.

Create a folder called **/var/spool/MIMEDefang**.

Find the service control code for `mimedefang` and put it in **/etc/init.d**. Make it executable. Open this code with an editor and look for section like so:

```
# Tricky stuff below... "echo -E" won't work, hence the two-step.
daemon $PROGDIR/$prog-multiplexor -p /var/spool/MIMEDefang/$prog-multiplexor.pid \
    $([ -n "$FILTER" ] && echo "-f $FILTER") \
    $([ -n "$SYSLOG_FACILITY" ] && echo "-S $SYSLOG_FACILITY") \
    $([ -n "$SUBFILTER" ] && echo "-F $SUBFILTER") \

... more lines follow with the same formatting...

    $([ "$MX_STATS_SYSLOG" = "yes" ] && echo "-T") \
    $([ "$MD_ALLOW_GROUP_ACCESS" = "yes" ] && echo "-G") \
    $([ -n "$MX_NOTIFIER" ] && echo "-O $MX_NOTIFIER") \
    echo "-U defang" \    <--------****** ADD THIS LINE ****
    -s $MX_SOCKET
```

Find the next section that starts like this:

```
daemon $PROGDIR/$prog -P /var/spool/MIMEDefang/$prog.pid \
    -m $MX_SOCKET \
    $([ -n "$LOOPBACK_RESERVED_CONNECTIONS" ] && echo "-R $LOOPBACK_RESERVED_CONNECTIONS") \
    $([ -n "$MX_USER" ] && echo "-U $MX_USER") \

... follow it down....

    $([ "$ALLOW_NEW_CONNECTIONS_TO_QUEUE" = "yes" ] && echo "-q") \
    echo "-U defang" \   <----------*** ADD THIS LINE ****
    -p $SOCKET
```

Follow this section of code down to right before the line "return $RETVAL". Add this line:

```
chmod oug+rw /var/spool/MIMEDefang/*.sock
```

If you don't, postfix won't be able to communicate with the `mimedefang` process.

Exit, save and add this to your services using chkconfig or whatever makes you happy.

Last step: open **/etc/postfix/main.cf** and add these lines:

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/spool/MIMEDefang/mimedefang.sock
milter_default_action = accept
```

Now - stop postfix, start mimedefang and then restart postfix. Check your logs for fun stuff and continue about your business.

Answer (score 4):

Going to chuck this in here since I just did this yesterday:

You don't have to roll your own anything. All you need is `postfix`, `libmilter`, and `mimedefang` the RPMs for which which are available in EPEL, so they should be available in other distros that actually stock *current* versions of packages rather than the 4-6 year old versions that EL repos do. But I digress.

On Centos 6.5 simply:

```
yum install mimedefang
```

which will spider out and get `sendmail-milter` [aka `libmilter`] as part of the dependencies. [SpamAssassin as well]

After this I recommend changing the socket settings for MIMEdefang to use an inet socket rather than a unix socket. This is mainly to avoid permissions issues since I can't be arsed to find a combination of user and permissions that works for both Postfix and MD.

in `/etc/sysconfig/mimedefang` uncomment and edit the `SOCKET` line to:

```
SOCKET=inet:10997
```

Make the port whatever you want, 10997 is my random choice.

Now:

```
service mimedefang start
chkconfig mimedefang on
```

And now you can simply add the milter config to `main.cf` or as an `smtpd -o` in `master.cf` like so:

```
smtpd_milters = inet:10997
```