# Mailcow Postfix & MIMEDefang integration

Tags: networking, email, postfix, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 server. I have installed [mailcow: dockerized](https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized/) as shown in their [documentation](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/i_u_m_install/) which includes Postfix among other tools. The mail server itself works without a problem, but I wanted to change large attachtments with links, so I started looking for solutions and found [MIMEDefang](https://mimedefang.org/) which as I read in some sources (the best one beign http://www.mickeyhill.com/mimedefang-howto/) can be used for that.

I tried to install and configure MIMEDefang using help from the second answer of this question: [How to integrate postfix and mimedefang](https://serverfault.com/questions/542679/how-to-integrate-postfix-and-mimedefang)
but it didn't work, and then I tried the first answer (inet instead of unix) and it didn't work either.

The problem I'm getting right now is that MIMEDefang is listening in inet:10997 but when reading Postfix logs after sending an email it says:

> postfix-mailcow_1    | Jan  7 14:58:57 3632dcaf9961 postfix/submission/smtpd[478]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:10997: Connection refused

My current configuration for postfix is the default that comes with mailcow and in /opt/mailcow-dockerized/data/conf/postfix/extra.cf I have:

```
mthostname = mail.mydomain.com
smtpd_milters = inet:rspamd:9900, inet:localhost:10997
```

mail.mydomain.com would be replaced by my actual domain.

In /etc/default/mimedefang I have just set:

```
SOCKET=inet:10997
```

I think it may have to do with Postfix beign dockerized but I honestly don't know how to make it work. If someone has any ideas I would be very grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

In `/opt/mailcow-dockerized/data/conf/postfix/extra.cf` instead of localhost you must put your ip (the VPS ip in my case):

Before:

```
mthostname = mail.mydomain.com
smtpd_milters = inet:rspamd:9900, inet:localhost:10997
```

After:

```
mthostname = mail.mydomain.com
smtpd_milters = inet:rspamd:9900, inet:148.54.11.25:10997
```

(148.54.11.25 is just an example)